# Android Retrofit - API call returns blank body

Tags: android, json, api, http, retrofit

I have this API that returns the user's information, but the returned json file returns a blank body. 
The API requests: User Token, User ID
The API response: a Profile object

API:

```
https://aujhfd1x3c.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/staging/users/{id}
```

interface method:

```
@GET("/staging/users/{id}")
    Call<Profile> getUserInfo(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") String id);
```

How I'm calling the API:

```
private void getUserInfo()
    {
        Log.d("Give me", "getUserInfo");
        Retrofit retrofit_getUserInfo = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://aujhfd1x3c.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        SoceroAPI api_getUserInfo = retrofit_getUserInfo.create(SoceroAPI.class);

        api_getUserInfo.getUserInfo(baroServiceProvider.getAuthToken().getToken(), inAppDatabase_userInfo.getData("user_ID"))
                .enqueue(new Callback<Profile>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Profile> call, Response<Profile> response)
                    {
                        Log.d("Give user info json", new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(response));
                        Log.d("Give me user info: ", "getUserInfo: onResponse: " + inAppDatabase_userInfo.getData("user_ID"));
                        Log.d("Give me first n now!!!", response.body().getFirstName()+"");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Profile> call, Throwable throwable)
                    {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    }
```

The log:

```
"body":{  },
   "rawResponse":{  
      "body":{  
         "contentLength":640,
         "contentType":{  
            "mediaType":"application/json",
            "subtype":"json",
            "type":"application"
         }
      },
      "code":200,
      "handshake":{  
         "cipherSuite":{  
            "javaName":"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
         },............................................
```

As you can see the body is blank `"body":{  }`. Therefore when I'm trying to print out the user's first name, it gives me a `null` value.
I checked if the API is working postman and works.
I'm also pretty sure my token id and user id is correct.

Comment: You should pull out `final Profile profile = response.body();` before you use it in any variables.

Comment: The response is already converted to 'Profile' pojo

Comment: No need for extra conversion then use Profile profile = response.body(); to get the profile.

Comment: You mean like this:
`final Profile p = response.body();
Log.d("Give me first n now!!!", p.getFirstName()+"");`

Comment: I'm not converting anything. I'm just printing out the json file because I want to actually see the call is returning.

Comment: Is it possible that having two fields named `body` is confusing the POJO converter?

Comment: I'm not the person who created the json files. So, I can't change the json file content.

Comment: Btw, my other APIs work using the similar approach that I'm doing. I believe passing the user ID to the call is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the api is responding properly by testing through the rest client... Also make sure Authorization and user id are valid. Code seems to have no error.. Make sure API endpoint is working well.